# How to change element in header of jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.5 and am trying to change the link color of an elment within the header. Due to the behaviour of jQuery mobile which is not loading the header again to create a smooth experience, the color will not change.

Exception, if I add data-ajax="false", then it will change. But there should be a way to avoid this.

My navi within the header:

```
<nav>
    <a href="/test/" id="nav_test" class="ui-link">TEST</a>
    <a href="/other/" id="nav_other" class="ui-link">OTHER</a>
</nav>
```

The jQuery code that will set the color of the active link to red:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log('nav_' +  window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
  $('#nav_' +  window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]).css('color', '#7e000b');
});
```

This works if I add data-ajax="false" to the a href tag.

How can I set the color without loading the entire header again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```js
$().ready(function(){
  let location = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  $('.ui-link').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 238)'); // reseting colors of all links
  switch (location) {
    case "test":
      $("#nav_"+location).css('color', '#7e000b')
      break;
    case "other":
      $("#nav_"+location).css('color', '#7e000b')
      break;
    default:
  }
  // onclick handler in case you arent doing an actual redirect (onepager)
  $('.ui-link').click(function(){
    location = $(this).id.split('_')[1];
    $('.ui-link').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 238)'); // reseting colors of all links
    $(this).css('color', '#7e000b'); // updating this link color
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a href="/test/" id="nav_test" class="ui-link">TEST</a>
    <a href="/other/" id="nav_other" class="ui-link">OTHER</a>
</nav>
```